# hanging branch after a git merge

Tags: git, gitlab

I am fairly new to git, and recently started to to use `git merge`. The first merge request went through successfully as I can see the master branch shows up the changes.

But I am a bit confused with the gitLab Graph.[image]

The first Graph is from the perspective of the feature branch (called 'rdrop'),
Next graph is the master branch.
:[image]

Could somebody explain **Why is it showing a hanging branch 'rdrop'?** and more importantly what exactly does this hanging branch mean?

I do understand the purpose of merge and also can understand the branching and merging graphs. But cannot understand what's happening here. There was no merge conflict too.

What I wanted to do was simply merge 'rdrop' to 'master'. That's all. I donot know how I landed in this mess.

**ADDITION TO ORIGINAL POST**

`$git log rdrop` gives this:

```
Main-iMac:nlp sm$ git log rdrop
commit d6283913c4c66b1f516b7eb54ddfee0e5c5ad482 (HEAD -> rdrop, rdrop/rdrop, main)
Author: Sanjay Mehrotra <xxxx@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 25 16:29:48 2019 +0530

    speeded up tokenisation.

commit fbf093d77021d0032b01fbaf86dfa7aa3429f735
Author: Sanjay Mehrotra <sanjmeh@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 25 15:59:31 2019 +0530

    first commit on rdrop. Small css change to test.

commit d10a58a1354be75b7ef92237039d16d52fc6f8bd (origin/master, master)
Author: rstudio <sanjmeh@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 25 14:34:38 2019 +0530

    app reverted from test mode title & color to normal title and color
```

**UPDATE**" Added output of: `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`

```
Main-iMac:nlp sm$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   2044225 (refs/stash) WIP on rdrop: d628391 speeded up tokenisation.
|\
| * 998ffdc index on rdrop: d628391 speeded up tokenisation.
|/
* d628391 (rdrop/rdrop, rdrop, main) speeded up tokenisation.
* fbf093d first commit on rdrop. Small css change to test.
| *   876bac8 (rdrop/master) Merge branch 'rdrop' into 'master'
| |\
|/ /
| * 79e469f (HEAD) Sample merge: deleted extra RDS files and one small CSS change
|/
* d10a58a (origin/master, master) app reverted from test mode title & color to normal title and color
* 1b7f430 removed stop button
*   5b54770 Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp
|\
| * 64feca3 Added message() in a function
| * f3040eb commit from aws server:  - still multi user clash occuring but now the frequent disconnection is gone.  - the replaceData(proxytable..) is replacing the DT of another user. - WIP
* |   66d3fa9 Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp
|\ \
| |/
| * b2e223d First commit from server. No code change. Just testing.
* | 46f6de0 Test mode css
```

Comment: Most likely, if you typed `git checkout master; git merge rdrop` in a local clone - that clone's view of `rdrop` was a couple of commits old. You can verify by running `git log rdrop` in that clone, if you haven't already updated it.

Comment: I did `git checkout master` and `git checkout rdrop` a couple of times or 3 times to see how the local files change. This I believe was a harmless command.

Comment: I have added the `git log rdrop` output to the original question for a trace of the commands. The merge was actually done on gitLab directly, so it seems is not captured in the local git log??

Comment: You've shown the same first three commits twice. Also, is `rdrop/rdrop` the upstream branch? Is it from the same repo as `origin/master`?

Comment: I think @Useless is correct. What you probably did was `git checkout master; git merge rdrop`. If wanted to make sure you had the latest branches when merging, you should have done `git checkout rdrop; git pull; git checkout master; git pull; git merge rdrop`

If you are only working on one machine, then you wouldn't have to worry about this. Are you only using one machine?

Comment: I am working on two machines. The other one is an AWS server.  I actually created `rdrop` branch in the aws machine as well. But didn't push anything from that machine as yet. Also @Useless you did make a useful comment and indeed I pasted the git log twice :-). Sorry for the confusion. I am going to start all over again, How can I clean this up for now?

Comment: Meanwhile in the process to go back to the latest version i tried to restore a particular commit by `git checkout 79e469fbcd63c5ef1e1e9a0845e7a7925aa75e75`. This did not restore the files commited that I see on the gitLab. Also my HEAD got detached. I am now lost.

Comment: I need to goback to [this version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wsy04bsc6hmo07p/Screenshot%202019-02-25%2023.20.01.png?dl=0)

Comment: You can use `git checkout -` to restore the state before the last checkout command, or just `git checkout master` or whatever to look at the current branch state. Detached head means you're looking at some revision other than the latest on a branch, that's all.

Comment: `git checkout master` asks me to stash local changes, which i did and then ran the command. This also does not bring me to the desired version. I then added (`git add`) one file just to test  (`get add outside.R`) and tried a `[git reflog]`( https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn13502sxi1fxgd/git_reflog.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 3):

Those are the same graphs.  They are just drawn a bit differently.

One looks like this (simplified a bit):

```
o
|
o
| o
| |
| o
 \|
  o
```

The other looks like this:

```
  o
  |
  o
o |
| |
o |
 \|
  o
```

They've just been flipped left-vs-right, with the last commit I've drawn shoved over a bit to make it look otherwise.

In both cases, the label `rdrop` points to the commit whose subject line is `speeded up tokenisation.`  The label `master` points to the commit whose subject line is `Merge branch rdrop into master.`  The parents of this merge commit are the commit whose subject line starts with `Sample merge: ...`, and the commit whose subject line begins with `app reverted from ...`.

That last commit is the third commit on `rdrop`, in both cases.  This implies the two commits on `rdrop` were added to `rdrop` after merging `rdrop` into `master`.

Comment: I understand that the two graphs are identical @torek and many thanks for your detailed explanation. I however do not think I added two commits after the merge. The last action was `merge`. In any any case the `git log` is now added to the original question, if that helps. The merge obviously is not shown in the git log.

Comment: More useful might be `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` but I suspect it will show the same graph—the merge you performed merged commit `app reverted from ...`, not commit `speeded up tokenisation.` Without seeing the exact sequence of commands, I can't tell you *why* it merged that commit, but that's what this shows.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see what commands you executed to reach the state you are in there. However, with that being said you are not in a mess, there can be a number of reasons you could have done to reach the state you are in.

One can be that you pushed rdrop into master when rdrop had only the "Sample merge: deleted extra RDS..." pushed onto it. After the merge, if you commited and pushed again other commits while you checked out on the rdrop branch, then those changes would appear as you have in the graph. So what you need to solve this, if you want to have the rdrop merged into master (those 2 commits), while you are checkout out onto rdrop do "git merge master"

You might also want to have a look at the [progit book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) which goes through some samples and explains how to use git like a pro :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Alex. I have downloaded the book and started reading. Also I am about to try out your suggested steps as soon as I understand a little more.

Comment: I think the problem turned out to be more complex. I have a subdirectory which has another .git subdirectory with another `master` branch. Sometimes the subdirectory git branch was checked out and since both of the repos referred to the same set of local files with different named remotes (`origin` and `nlp`) the resulting branching got mixed up. But I think this is a good case study for learning git. Therefore I am opening a new question with all details of the two repos. Hopefully I will see you guys there.

Comment: I have asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54923907/1972786). This is now more detailed and more challenging. Folks who attempted to help me here are at an advantage to answer it correctly there. Hoping to see some of you git experts there.