# why does git commit take me back in time on the master branch?

Tags: git

I have a very silly situation that has unnecessary complicated my git setup. I have spent last few days pulling my hair when my commits (many times) are taking me back in time.

I am wanting someone to analyse and come up with an explanation as to how this is happening and only after this is clear we want to get out of this mess. This should be an excellent case study for starters in git too.

So, purely by oversight I initialized a git repo in `~/nlp` and another git repo in `~/nlp/annotate`. Before I realised that I had two repos I started committing and pushing into the same remote (hosted on [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh)).

As if this was not enough I also accidentally defined one remote as: `[remote "nlp"]` and another as `[remote "origin"]`. (*perhaps age is catching up on me*).

And then to top it all, I have a server (AWS ubuntu machine where I usually `git pull` the code and occasionally `git push` from to the same gitlab repo.

So in effect we have 3 local repos pushing on to the same remote (with different names).

To super complicate the matter, there are independent `.gitignore` files on the server and my local machine with *different* set of files setup inside them.

For diagnosis I will reproduce the outputs of  `git branch` and `git log` from each of the three local repos.

> local mac: `~/nlp`

```
Main-iMac:nlp sm$ git branch -vv
      checkout    2647194 now added studqa3.csv - was missed earlier
      main        d628391 speeded up tokenisation.
    * master      301e7f6 [origin/master: ahead 1] the code worked on shinyapps.io
      rdrop       d628391 [rdrop/rdrop] speeded up tokenisation.
      shinyServer 0a35421 [origin/shinyServer] adding 3 new files in annotate
      shiny_sm    ff32074 [origin/shiny_sm] changes in q & a (editing pre existing q&a) shiny app working prototype
```

> local mac: `~/nlp/annotate`: (this is the subdirectory)

```
Main-iMac:annotate sm$ git branch -vv
* master d90c690 Checking a repeat commit from subdirectory
```

> aws ubuntu server (local dir): `~/nlp` (this is the main dir on server)

```
studio@ip-172-31-30-19:~/nlp$ git branch --v
* master    e652dc9 added back mandira new
  rdrop_aws 6be4e81 approvals
```

> git log of local iMac parent directory: `~/nlp`

```
Main-iMac:nlp sm$ git log --source --decorate --oneline --all --graph
* 301e7f6       refs/heads/master (HEAD -> master) the code worked on shinyapps.io
* c8b7235       refs/remotes/origin/master (origin/master) new app for rdrop testing
* c9df566       refs/remotes/origin/master new & simpler validate function for studqa positions only
* e652dc9       refs/remotes/origin/master added back mandira new
* daa9d78       refs/remotes/origin/master committing after the merged users.csv
* 57ecbb7       refs/remotes/origin/master merge users.csv
* 950c30b       refs/remotes/origin/master checking out one file delete on AWS server, to see if it syncs back to local
* 76e0580       refs/remotes/origin/master added 2 more students (old names)
* 430c7fa       refs/remotes/origin/master added a few more columns in student results function
* c716532       refs/remotes/origin/master dupques updated
* 2dcfc1c       refs/remotes/origin/master latest approvals added
* 34a1dd7       refs/remotes/origin/master first commit of servfunc.R - not needed in local machine.
* 06d8304       refs/remotes/origin/master approvals
* 8c801ea       refs/remotes/origin/master Removed the regex bug
*   16c7e54     refs/remotes/origin/master Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp
|\
| * 7e925c8     refs/remotes/origin/master improved the table filter of DT for admim
| *   1054bb7   refs/remotes/origin/master I feel this was a dangerous merge. Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp
| |\
| | *   a9d5d85 refs/remotes/origin/master Merge branch 'rdrop' into 'master'
| | |\
| | | * d628391 refs/heads/main (rdrop/rdrop, origin/rdrop, rdrop, main) speeded up tokenisation.
| | | * fbf093d refs/heads/main first commit on rdrop. Small css change to test.
| * | | 192a02f refs/remotes/origin/master Adding outside.R - and using nlp parent git
| | |/
| |/|
* | | 6be4e81   refs/remotes/origin/master approvals
|/ /
| | *   6b26385 refs/stash (refs/stash) WIP on (no branch): 876bac8 Merge branch 'rdrop' into 'master'
| | |\
| |/ /
| | * b094d2f   refs/stash index on (no branch): 876bac8 Merge branch 'rdrop' into 'master'
| |/
```

> git log of local iMac subdirectory `~/nlp/annotate`

```
Main-iMac:annotate sm$ git log --source --decorate --oneline --all --graph
* d90c690       refs/heads/master (HEAD -> master) Checking a repeat commit from subdirectory
* 9f454d1       refs/heads/master remove staging for deleted file
* 28f9fcd       refs/heads/master cat changed to message
* 6a2d89c       refs/heads/master all data files
* 45f000a       refs/remotes/nlp/master (nlp/master) updated pull_all_studqa()
* 39cdd99       refs/remotes/nlp/master LUCI title changed
* d6cfc2c       refs/remotes/nlp/master Removed transfer of property keywords
* b21668b       refs/remotes/nlp/master Just a few cosmetic changes
* cdd1d02       refs/remotes/nlp/master as_tibble removed
* bebfb4f       refs/remotes/nlp/master new functions: smoothen, remdir, remove_old_dir, fixed content_len bug
* 3d88ec3       refs/remotes/nlp/master All data files..
* e21f377       refs/remotes/nlp/master synching new 44 student creds and initial data files in all 44 directories. If any dir missed will do another commit.
* 8ea59e4       refs/remotes/nlp/master deleted a RDS file
* af7aaa0       refs/remotes/nlp/master ONLY ADMIN PANEL changes. - added new css tags - changes in search strings / admin panel - new paradty pdty4.rds hardcoded.* 18c640d       refs/remotes/nlp/master New functions added with css changes. Bug in remove_hyphen removed. Completely overhauled val_studqa()
* 82b1f4a       refs/remotes/nlp/master lots of changes not committed earlier
* df16b92       refs/remotes/nlp/master fill=T added
* 037d0bb       refs/remotes/nlp/master changed the highlighted text to red font and increased font size and line space for paragraphs.
* 30acdb2       refs/remotes/nlp/master changed datetime to as.character in tail table - also changed from DT to normal tableOutput
* 5f678a3       refs/remotes/nlp/master changed to users.csv
* 6e6cd54       refs/remotes/nlp/master dhruv directory
* 7ed1fd2       refs/remotes/nlp/master abhiroop, aditya, apurva uploaded
* 942f363       refs/remotes/nlp/master Data files being uploaded needed for launch.
* 5dcfe1a       refs/remotes/nlp/master simple comment changes.
* 9c358ff       refs/remotes/nlp/master with changes that were done long ago.
* 0f8ff9d       refs/remotes/nlp/master all deleted files synced.
* 4f90df2       refs/remotes/nlp/master deleted unused user directories
* ba6a339       refs/remotes/nlp/master new files added for initializing missing data tables for new students.
* 2a59217       refs/remotes/nlp/master new users loaded for JAN launch.
* a4cf17f       refs/remotes/nlp/master Host of fucntions used for splitting and reassigning data for students changed.  - add_acts is overhauled on para level split.  - Case splitt
ing logic overhauled.  - User directory logic improved.* 28902e3       refs/remotes/nlp/master While admin module has many changes this version is ready for annotations for students. Not yet ready for admin.
* df4d0c6       refs/remotes/nlp/master Started to add FILTER tab with data mgmt.. WIP. WOrks to display all cases.
```

> git log of ubuntu server local directory `~/nlp`:

```
rstudio@ip-172-31-30-19:~/nlp$  git log --source --decorate --oneline --all --graph
* e652dc9       refs/heads/master (HEAD -> master) added back mandira new
* daa9d78       refs/heads/master committing after the merged users.csv
* 57ecbb7       refs/heads/master merge users.csv
* 950c30b       refs/heads/master checking out one file delete on AWS server, to see if it syncs back to local
* 76e0580       refs/heads/master added 2 more students (old names)
* 430c7fa       refs/heads/master added a few more columns in student results function
* c716532       refs/heads/master dupques updated
* 2dcfc1c       refs/heads/master latest approvals added
* 34a1dd7       refs/heads/master first commit of servfunc.R - not needed in local machine.
* 06d8304       refs/heads/master approvals
* 8c801ea       refs/heads/master Removed the regex bug
*   16c7e54     refs/heads/master Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp
|\
| * 7e925c8     refs/heads/master improved the table filter of DT for admim
| *   1054bb7   refs/heads/master I feel this was a dangerous merge. Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp
| |\
| | *   a9d5d85 refs/heads/master Merge branch 'rdrop' into 'master'
| | |\
| | | * d628391 refs/heads/master speeded up tokenisation.
| | | * fbf093d refs/heads/master first commit on rdrop. Small css change to test.
| | * |   876bac8       refs/heads/master Merge branch 'rdrop' into 'master'
| | |\ \
| | | |/
| | |/|
| | | * 79e469f refs/heads/master Sample merge: deleted extra RDS files and one small CSS change
| | |/
| * | 192a02f   refs/heads/master Adding outside.R - and using nlp parent git
| |/
* | 6be4e81     refs/heads/rdrop_aws (rdrop_aws) approvals
|/
* d10a58a       refs/heads/master app reverted from test mode title & color to normal title and color
* 1b7f430       refs/heads/master removed stop button
*   5b54770     refs/heads/master Merge branch 'master' of https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp
|\
| * 64feca3     refs/heads/master Added message() in a function
| * f3040eb     refs/heads/master commit from aws server:  - still multi user clash occuring but now the frequent disconnection is gone.  - the replaceData(proxytable..) is replacing the DT of anotheruser. - WIP
```

**Update**
remote tracking information could be useful too.

```
Main-iMac:annotate sm$ git remote -v
nlp     https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp (fetch)
nlp     https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp (push)
```

and

```
Main-iMac:annotate sm$ cd ..
Main-iMac:nlp sm$ git remote -v
origin  https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp.git (push)
rdrop   https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp.git (fetch)
rdrop   https://gitlab.com/sanjmeh/nlp.git (push)
```

The challenge is to figure out why I am getting my new commits overturned by future commits.

Thanks to anyone who undertakes the challenge.

Comment: These are rather hard to read. There *are* a few commits with the same abbreviated hash IDs, e.g., `06d8304` and `6be4e81` appear in more than one repository. But since there are so many that are unique to one, and `git log` walks the tree in date order without showing the graph unless you use `--graph`, it's really hard to say much. Try adding `--graph` to your `--oneline` logs.

Comment: replaced the logs with `--graph` option. Also increased their lengths to give a little longer history.

Comment: From the updated graphs, I see that `e652dc9` is the first (last? endpoint, anyway) *share* commit in two of the three repositories. Note that all history "before" this point—commits below it, in the `log --graph` output—is the same in both repositories. The iMac `~/nlp/annotate` repository looks unrelated to the other two: its branch-tip `master` (`d90c690`) commit is found nowhere else, and its remote-tracking name `nlp/master` (`45f000a`) commit is likewise found nowhere else. I did not check all the commits "behind" those two points, but if the graphs are complete, the [cont'd]

Comment: ... the lack of structure behind them means they can't match the other two repos, which do otherwise match. Note that label names on commits (such as `refs/heads/master` or `refs/remotes/nlp/master`) are mainly for convenience. If they're inconvenient, as in this case, throw them away and use the commit hash IDs, which are very real and, in essence, *are* the commits.